# Why do (some?) flies aggregate on both sides of a window even when there is no passage between the two sides?

Tags: behaviour, sociality

I've observed an interesting behavior in flies that often invade old houses. When flies accumulate on the inside of a window, I've noticed that other flies start to accumulate on the outside of the same window. Interestingly, this occurs even when there's no passage for air or pheromones between the inside and outside.

To eliminate some possibilities:

- The inside area is dark, and the flies are attracted to the external light, so light attraction for the external flies can be ruled out.
- The use of an aerial insecticide affects only the flies on the inside, confirming that there's no passage for air or pheromones between the two sides.

Is there any biological explanation for why flies would behave this way?

Comment: Aerosol insecticides are only effective at quite high concentrations. There could easily still be passage of air/scent/pheromones from one side to the other without reaching the concentrations effective to kill on the opposite side. Dilution will play a big role here. Small amounts leaking through will be diluted enough to be ineffective, but something like pheromones or other things insects are sensitive to at very low concentrations might still be detectable.

Comment: I think the answer is a compound statistical effect. First, both window sides correlate with the overall density of flies in the area, 2nd, you only notice an accumulation of flies above a certain threshold (total number), which makes it likely that there are flies on both sides.